# Multi Tenancy No longer working after Spring Boot update

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate

I had multi tenancy working correctly since then we have updated spring boot to 2.4.3. I have now come back to project and merged in the code base and this as now broken the tenant switching.

Here is my Hibernate configuration

```
public class HibernateConfig {

    @Autowired
    private JpaProperties jpaProperties;

    @Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
        return new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource,
             MultiTenantConnectionProvider multiTenantConnectionProvider,
             HibernateProperties hibernateProperties) {

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(UppStudentAppBeApplication.class.getPackage().getName());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter());

        Map<String, Object> jpaPropertiesMap = hibernateProperties.determineHibernateProperties(jpaProperties.getProperties(), new HibernateSettings());
        //jpaPropertiesMap.putAll(jpaProperties.getProperties());
        jpaPropertiesMap.put(Environment.MULTI_TENANT, MultiTenancyStrategy.SCHEMA);
        jpaPropertiesMap.put(Environment.MULTI_TENANT_CONNECTION_PROVIDER, multiTenantConnectionProvider);
        jpaPropertiesMap.put(Environment.MULTI_TENANT_IDENTIFIER_RESOLVER, TenantContext.TenantIdentifierResolver.class);

        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaPropertyMap(jpaPropertiesMap);

        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }
}
```

Here is my tenant context

```
public class TenantContext {

    public static final String DEFAULT_TENANT_IDENTIFIER = "public";

    private static final ThreadLocal<String> TENANT_IDENTIFIER =
            new ThreadLocal<>();

    public static void setTenant(String tenantIdentifier) {
        TENANT_IDENTIFIER.set(tenantIdentifier);
    }

    public static void reset() {
        TENANT_IDENTIFIER.remove();
    }

    public static String getTenant() { return TENANT_IDENTIFIER.get(); }

    @Component
    public static class TenantIdentifierResolver implements CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver {
        @Override
        public String resolveCurrentTenantIdentifier() {
            String currentTenantId = TENANT_IDENTIFIER.get();
            return currentTenantId != null ?
                    currentTenantId :
                    DEFAULT_TENANT_IDENTIFIER;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean validateExistingCurrentSessions() {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

I can see while debugging that the connection.setSchema() is setting the dbSchema correctly but the switch isn't taking effect and is staying within the public schema.

This is my MultiTenantConnectionProvider.

```
@Component
public class TenantConnectionProvider implements MultiTenantConnectionProvider {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TenantConnectionProvider.class);

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    public TenantConnectionProvider(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    @Override
    public Connection getAnyConnection() throws SQLException {
        return dataSource.getConnection();
    }

    @Override
    public void releaseAnyConnection(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        connection.close();
    }

    @Override
    public Connection getConnection(String tenantIdentifier) throws SQLException {
        logger.info("Get connection for tenant  " + String.join(":", tenantIdentifier ));
        final Connection connection = getAnyConnection();
        try {
            connection.setSchema(tenantIdentifier);
            if(tenantIdentifier != TenantContext.DEFAULT_TENANT_IDENTIFIER) {
                connection.createStatement().execute("SET search_path to "+ tenantIdentifier +",public;");
            }
        } catch ( SQLException e ) {
            throw new HibernateException(
                    "Could not alter JDBC connection to specified schema [" +
                            tenantIdentifier + "]",
                    e
            );
        }
        return connection;
    }

    @Override
    public void releaseConnection(String tenantIdentifier, Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        try {
            //connection.createStatement().execute( String.format("SET SCHEMA \"%s\";", TenantContext.DEFAULT_TENANT_IDENTIFIER) );
            connection.setSchema(TenantContext.DEFAULT_TENANT_IDENTIFIER);
        } catch ( SQLException e ) {
            throw new HibernateException(
                    "Could not alter JDBC connection to specified schema [" +
                            tenantIdentifier + "]",
                    e
            );
        }
        releaseAnyConnection(connection);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supportsAggressiveRelease() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isUnwrappableAs(Class unwrapType) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T unwrap(Class<T> unwrapType) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I currently don't understand what it's stopped working or if I am missing something but at present I am just going over things I have found from googling.

Comment: I have same issue can someone help here..

Comment: In my case, tenant getting through tenant interceptor but not working when we change in the same thread using switch tenant.